# Creating JButtons dynamically

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jbutton

Hello I have this set up

```
private JButton btnFoo, btnBar;
```

And I need to get for each button the following

```
        btnFoo = new JButton("Foo");
    btnFoo.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnFoo);
```

Is it possible in Java to create this dynamically for each button I declare?
because when I have like 5 buttons I don't want 3x5 = 15 lines of code but only a few lines with dynamically created buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a little loop and store your buttons in an array:

```
private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[5];

String names[] = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Fob", "Bao"};
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i)
{
    JButton btn = new JButton(names[i]);
    btn.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn);
    buttons[i] = btn;
}
```

Comment: what exactly does buttons[i] = btn; do?

Comment: @Thorvason: It stores the pointer to the newly created JButton object in the array of `JButton` pointers called `buttons` (which is created at the first line).

Comment: thank you, bc I am currently using this in my project where I create Jbuttons based on an input xml file, and this was one of the major point in  this

Answer (score 2):

That's where arrays and loops come to help. Use a button array and iterate over it.
But if you worry about identifiers, then using `HashMap<String, JButton>` might be a good way.

```
Map<String, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<String, JButton>();
map.put("fooButton", new JButton());
...
```

By iterating over the entry set (just a few lines of code), set the `ActionListener` for the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

```
        boton1= new JButton();
        boton1.setText(" Calcular ");
        add(boton1);
        boton1.setActionCommand("Calcular");
        boton1.addActionListener(this);
        boton1.setEnabled(true);

        String nB2="boton";


        for(int j=2; j<4; j++){
            JButton botonGenerico = new JButton(nB2+j);
            botonGenerico.setText("Calcular"+j);
            add(botonGenerico);
            botonGenerico.setActionCommand("Calcular"+j);
            botonGenerico.addActionListener(this);
            botonGenerico.setEnabled(true);


        }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String a = e.getActionCommand();

    if(a.equals("Calcular")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡boton 1");

        }
    if(a.equals("Calcular2")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡boton 2");

        }
    if(a.equals("Calcular3")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡boton 3");

        }

}
```