# Button (android.content.Context) in Button Cannot be Applied to (Java.lang.Object)

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I am attempting to Dynamically Create Buttons to match Data Table. I was using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612791/creating-jbuttons-dynamically) as a reference point however I keep getting this error code: `Button (android.content.Context) in Button Cannot be Applied to (Java.lang.Object)`
I tried multiple things to alleviate error code but I am at a loss of how to fix it I attempted to set the Map to an array but that isn't working either. The Code has successfully counted, and displayed the data but I cannot get it to add the Needed Buttons.

```
 Backendless.Data.of( "Store" ).find( queryBuilder, new AsyncCallback<List<Map>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse( List<Map> response )
                    {

                       int numBrands = response.size();

                       Button brandButtons[] = new Button[numBrands];

          System.out.println("The Count of Buttons:" + numBrands);

           ArrayList<Brands> productList  = new ArrayList<>();



             Object[] arrayList = {response};
            for(int i = 0; i < brandButtons.length; i++)
                        {

                        Button brans = new Button(productList[i]);

                            brans.setOnClickListener();
                            add(brans);
                            brandButtons[i] = brans;




                            //Object element = thisIsAStringArray[i];
                            System.out.println( "List of Brands" + response );




                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here in this line:

```
Button brans = new Button(productList[i]); // here
```

[**`Button`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) class expects **`Context`** passed to it's constructor invocation & you're passing Object type instead.

Use like this,

```
Button brans = new Button(context); // here context can be activity or fragment.

//now use this brans object to set property to your programmatically created Button, 
//don't forget to add it to your parent view afterwards
```

Comment: Just a Stupid Oversight on my part, Thank you

Comment: Haha, no issues, happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) documentation, to create a button object you need to pass a `Context` object. In your code your passing an object of `Brands` which is causing the problem.

The solution would be to pass a context to the `Button(Context)` constructor. If your in an Activity it would be something like new `Button(YourActivity.this)`, in a fragment you could use `new Button(getContext())`